# How know if right click is on a "text being edited" not/before "text changed" event in winforms?

Tags: winforms, grid, contextmenu, contextmenustrip

My question might be simple but I couldn't find specific answer on web. 

I have a winforms application with a grid inside, in which I have implemented a context menu to be shown on right click on cells. These cells include text elements that can be edited. When user clicks or double clicks on the cell, the text can be edited and that's what I want. 
The problem is when the text is in edit mode and user right clicks on it again, 2 context menus are shown on each other. One is my context menu and the other is windows right click on text including options like copy, paste etc.
 

I wonder if there is any event like "text being edited" or "windows default context menu opened" that can be used for such scenarios? Or what is the proper way of solving this problem, which I guess must be a common one. 
In these cases I want to show only the windows right-click menu, not mine.

Comment: Assuming that the "Grid" is a DataGridView, you could set a flag in the `CellBeginEdit()` event and reset the flag in the `CellEndEdit()` event. Check the flag before showing your context menu. Maybe, specify which Control you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need the Control.GotFocus event: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

You could look for focus, then prevent right clicks in the control until the control has lost focus (Control.LostFocus). If the control gets focus *from* a right click, then you could open your context menu (I think).